# How do you access data from your I Series in ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net, linq, ibm-midrange

All of our current ASP.Net web apps access our IBM I Series using an ODBC connection and command object. Should I move to another way of accessing it? How do you current access your I Series when your ASP.Net app needs data from it? There has to be a better way.

I recently saw [this](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.ms.doc/doc/c0054118.html) article about IBM supporting Linq to Entities with a specific client version on the web server. To me, that seems like the more long term route to go but would like more feedback. I get the vibe from MS that Linq to Entities is the long term route they plan to go. Is that the feeling others are getting too?

Answer (score 1):

I am using the drivers supplied by IBM.  The beauty of this is that we can use a single DataAccess object built on the enterprise library application blocks and not create a bunch of custom code for the iSeries connections.

```
Provider=IBMDA400.DataSource.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Why does there "need to be a better way"? What's the problem with the way you're using that you're trying to avoid? Are you, perhaps, using SQL directly in your web pages? Are you missing a data-access-layer, or object-relation-mapper? Seems to me a well designed system with a nice business object layer wouldn't really care about the actual connection to the 400.

Comment: Agreed. Just after using Linq, subsonic, and other ORM-ish products, using ODBC just seems a bit antiquated. What I miss the most is the development environment integration and type safe features that ORMs have. That's why I wanted to see if there was a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the IBM managed provider to access ISeries and that has been working out just great.

IBM have some RedBook resources on it [here](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg246440.html?Open).

In the applications I've written so far towards ISeries it hasn't been justified to use any ORM, but if the need would arise I would definately go for [NHibernate](http://www.nhibernate.org/).